# Android Studio Binding classes throwing errors after leaving and reopening project

Tags: android

On android studio, I will, after logging out the day before, open a project, and when I do, occasionally all of the Data Binding methods will be marked as errors. I am not sure why this is happening. The project still works when I click run, but I was just wondering if there is a solution to this so I don't have errors everywhere. So far, I have tried to rebuild the project and used Invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: After running you haven;t any error so your code is correct. It just needs time to run one time.

Comment: Yes I have run the app a couple of times and it runs fine, but the android studio IDE is still saying that there are errors in my code and my question is more so how do I make it stop saying I have errors when the app runs fine

Comment: It depends to the errors, what are they?

Comment: I am following the udacity beginner's android development tutorial and the binding variable is type ActivityMainBinding which is labeled in my code as an error. Therefore, when I call binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) the setContentView method is also underlined and labeled as an error

Comment: You mean it is red?

Comment: Yes, ActivityMainBinding and the setContentView method are both red

Comment: They are red but code runs correctly?

Comment: Yes, which doesn't make any sense and I want the code not to be red because it is tripping me up with all of the error indicators everywhere.

Comment: When you put your mouse on that line, which error it shows?

Comment: Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding. I did make sure that data binding is enabled in build.gradle as well.

Comment: Your AS is updated?

Comment: Yes my AS is up to date. I also want to mention that sometimes when I log on there errors are there and other times the errors aren't there.

Comment: If sometimes you have errors and sometimes you haven't, it seems that it is bug of AS. Maybe clean and rebuild the project help you.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help!

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project helps you?

Comment: Yeah, it seemed to work as a temporary solution, but when I opened the project back up today I have the same problem.

Comment: I post my comment as answer, you can check it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You can do some works to solve this problem, it maybe a bug of Android Studio:
1- Go to file>invalidate caches/restart
2- Clean and rebuild the project